# Remove HTML tags from string saved in database - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, database, vb.net

I am using ASP.NET 2.0 and SQL Server 2005.

I am saving a value/string in the database such as............

```
<P>Test 1</P><P>Test2</P>
```

Now i want to decode/remove the html tags and display it properly to the user such as....

> Test 1
>
> Test 2

I have tried this but it does not work!

```
txtDesc.Text = VALUE FROM DATABASE
```

What am i doing wrong? This must be a problem in ASP.NET 2.0?

***Edit:***

I am setting the value to a Text box where the TEXTMODE property of the text box is set to MULITILINE for scroll. Setting it to a normal Label work but not for my text box.......

Comment: What about it doesn't work? It doesn't strip the tags? Does it do anything to the angle brackets (<>) or does it escape them?

Comment: It's not changing anything, it still just displays the WHOLE string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ltrDesc.Text = Value from database

<div style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:scroll">
    <asp:Literal ID="ltrDesc" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Comment: It works in ASP.NET 3.5 yes, but not in 2.0 for some reason, it displayed the HTML tags to the user as well in 2.0.

Comment: Hi, try Literal control instead of Label.

Comment: Literal Control works yes thanks, but I want to place the text inside a text box multiple rows so if the text is long the user must be able to scroll and you cant do this with a Literal control.

Comment: Oh dear, i see it works fine with a normal label as well, just not when i place the value into a text box with the text mode = Multiline

Comment: Then use a Textbox with Multiline = true and Readonly = true: txtDesc.Text = VALUE from DATABASE

Comment: Just set textbox's text, you don't need a label.

Comment: You can use a div with style="overflow:scroll" to make it scrollable.

Comment: Thanks! I just found that i can add a scroll bar to a label as well by doing this <asp:Label ID="Label4" Style="overflow-y:scroll;" runat="server" Text="Label" Height="64px" Width="248px"></asp:Label>

Answer (score 0):

To display text with html tags, Literal, PlaceHolder, Panel server controls support better.